# Solve the 2nd order homogeneous ODE with complex co-efficients.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the second order ODE : $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-p^2y=0$ , where $p$ is a **complex constant**.

Take , $p=a+ib$,  where $b\not=0$. Then how I solve this ? If $b=0$ then auxiliary equation is $m^2-p^2=0\implies m=\pm p$. But when $b\not=0$ then , $m=\pm (a+ib)$. That is we have two distinct complex roots. How do I write the general solution of this equation in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

This stays the same as with the real roots,
$$
y=c_1e^{(a+ib)x}+c_2e^{-(a+ib)x}
$$
with complex constants $c_1,c_2$.